# Grouping collections of lines into array elements by a delimiter

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I am attempting to take output from a command that looks like this:

```
Thing ID: 1234
    Object_Name = MyObject1
    Object_Owner = MeMyselfAndI

Thing ID: 5678
    Object_Name = MyObject2
    Object_Owner = MeMyselfAndI
```

and throw these collections of lines into their own elements in an array like this (where the brackets delimit an element of the array):

```
MyArray =

[   Thing ID: 1234
        Object_Name = MyObject1
        Object_Owner = MeMyselfAndI   ]
[   Thing ID: 5678
        Object_Name = MyObject2
        Object_Owner = MeMyselfAndI   ]
```

such that retrieval of an element, like

```
${MyArray[0]})
```

would result in the following:

```
Thing ID: 1234
    Object_Name = MyObject1
    Object_Owner = MeMyselfAndI
```

In other words, I'd like to use "Thing ID:" as a delimiter here (of sorts), but keep it in each of the array elements.  Is this possible in bash?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk to insert `\0` after each block and use that output to create array:

```
arr=()

while IFS= read -rd '' line; do
   arr+=("${line#$'\n'}")
done < <(awk -v RS= '{print $0 "\0"}' file)
```

**Check output:**

```
echo "${arr[0]}"
Thing ID: 1234
    Object_Name = MyObject1
    Object_Owner = MeMyselfAndI    
echo "${arr[1]}"    
Thing ID: 5678
    Object_Name = MyObject2
    Object_Owner = MeMyselfAndI
```

Comment: Note that you have (unwanted) leading newline in field 1 of `arr`…